# How to add row selection checkbox in data table?

Tags: php, datatables

Hi i want to add the **row selection** **check box** in data table, also need to add the check box against every row. So that it will select the row **individually**.

Thanks.

Comment: no clue about your working env, what kind of language, framework?

Comment: I am working in php framework, and i have added the datatable to show the result from databade.

Comment: Check this links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671815/how-can-i-add-a-check-box-to-a-data-table-to-be-used-to-delete-the-selected-row

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794430/update-database-table-with-checkboxes-php-mysql

Comment: Thanks, will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code 
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

HTML

```
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a feeling this wouldnt add the checkbox if you used `row.add([])`